How to get Nacon Pro Compact controller working on ubuntu?
I have tried xpadneo and it does not detect controller and I am running out of options as xpad does not work ether. anyone have a work around for this xbox controller? I am on the latest kubuntu 14.10

Kubuntu 14.10 is LONG since dead. Are you sure that's the version of Kubuntu you are using?
